# Second book on linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Having gone through most of howard anton and chris rorres elementary linear algebra at my school. We have gone through some proofs, but the main focus was how to turn problems into matrices and then compute.
We covered
Vector spaces, determinants, linear transformations, diagonalization eigenvectors and inner products.
Im interestes in having a stronger background in linear algebra. Especially in terms of proofs in vector spaces and linear mappings, could someone suggest a book for this?

Comment: There are many threads already that discuss linear algebra books. But in your situation I recommend Friedberg, Insel, and Spence.

Comment: you can try *Linear algebra done right* of Sheldon Axler if you want to develop an intuition about the main results of linear algebra behind the calculus using matrices and determinants.

Comment: I second Masacroso's suggestion of Axler's book. Another one (a bit more theoretical and with more advanced topics as well) is by Hoffmann and Kunze.

Comment: I just started algebra 1, with a ring first approach. Should I skip axler and start on Hoffmann and Kunze? Or should I start working thorugh axler?

Comment: Whatever book you use, you might also want to take a look at the videos that accompany Linear Algebra Done Right: http://linear.axler.net/LADRvideos.html

Comment: Thank you, that is good service. :) I already ordered it. It seems like a good book for second course whereas hoffmann and kunze is more suitable as a 3rd book on linear algebra

Answer (score 1):

According to me book written by Hall and Knight is awesome. But just see the edition. Insel is also good one.

Comment: If I am not mistaken Hall and Knight's book is on Higher Algebra (sort of advanced High School Algebra type) and does not have much (except some tidbits) to do with Linear Algebra.